# Regular Expression: validation for comma separatable string

Tags: regex, string, validation

I need a regular expression that will be able to validate a Strings such as;

```
"", "0", "1,2", "2,3", "1,2,3"
```

1. when if a '0' occurs, then other numbers will not (e.g. "0,1" not allowed),
2. number range is variable it can be minimum of 2 and maximum of n,
3. duplicate numbers are not allowed like "1,2,2,3",
4. there is no need to be a sequence, for example "1,3,4" is valid.
5. strings are not nested. we never check for instance ""0", "1,2"".
6. n is maximum of 10, but variable, as i stated.

Comment: A regular expression is very unlikely to be the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: Never do this kind of stuff with `regexp`.

Comment: I think it would be relatively simple with regexp except for the combination of 3 and 4. At least I don't know a simple way to combine those. By the way, I am assuming you have each of those strings separately and that is not actually one string that includes double quotes. Can you clarify that in your question?

Comment: I added 5th and 6th conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to check (relatively) complicated rules, you'd better be off splitting the input into an array: `string.split(",");` and iterate over it checking the necessary conditions.

Comment: I firstly used this approach indeed, but many things must be checked then (nullity, 0 condition, duplication, etc) requires many string operations. I thought I wonder whether it is possible to do all that checks in a single or at most at two lines of code.

Comment: You need a virtually unbound amount of memory (since the maximum is `n`, which may be high, and you need to have back-references to _all_ numbers.) When compiled, a regex can be converted into an [FSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) which can only implement a fixed amount of memory, so this class of problems cannot be solved by regular expressions/FSMs in the general case.